# Что такое COM объект

Tags: com

Искал в интернете информацию о том, что такое COM объект, ничего понятного не нашел.
Объясните пожалуйста:

**1) Что такое COM объект**

**2) Для чего нужен**

**В вики нашел следующее:**
*...предназначенный для создания программного обеспечения на основе взаимодействующих компонентов, каждый из которых может использоваться во многих программах одновременно*

**Как он влияет на создание программного обеспечения?**

**Как взаимодействуют компоненты?**

**Как они используются во многих программах одновременно**

Пожалуйста, приведите пример

Comment: Вот вы, допустим, нарисовали схему в Microsoft Visio, скопировали её и вставили в документ word. После этого вы можете дважды щёлкнуть на вставленную картинку, и приложение visio откроется внутри окна word, и схему можно будет редактировать. Это и есть com-обьект, загружаемый программой word.

Comment: @maestro то, что вы описали, называется OLE, а не COM. Вот здесь хорошо раскрывается разница, в том числе даётся хорошее на мой взгляд определение COM: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/514598/what-is-the-difference-between-com-and-ole. А пример COM - это интерфейсы DirectX.